# Compensate or fix VHS artefacts in areas of high contrast

Tags: video, video-capture, vhs, virtualdub, avisynth

Take a look at the man in a tuxedo. To the right of the black leg, there is a bright vertical line.

Is there some kind of filter in something like VirtualDub or Vapoursynth which could improve this aspect of the picture?

[image: Picture of a wedding cake exhibiting artefact from capture process or intrinsic to composite video, still frame taken from VHS tape]

Comment: .... crickets..